# Evaluating functions: Simplifying complex fraction with mixed variables

Tags: calculus, functions

I’m stumped on a basic calculus problem in what seems to be a simple problem:

Evaluate the difference quotient for the function. Simplify.

$f(a) = \frac{1}{a}  , \frac{f(a) - f(b)}{ a - b}$ Answer: $\frac{-1 }{ ab}$.

The obvious plug and play lands on: 
$\frac{f(a) - f(b)}{ a - b} = \frac{1/a - 1/b}{a - b}$.

If I take the GCF for the numerator I can get:
$\frac{b}{ab} - \frac{a }{ ab}$
This leaves $\frac{b - a}{ ab (a - b)}$
Which leaves $\frac{ab - b^2 - a^2 - ab }{ ab}$
Which leaves $- b^2 - a^2 - ab$

Admittedly, I’m rusty, and went through multiple techniques, but just can’t arrive st the answer. I’m sure I’m missing something fundamental I need to review. Thank you all for your support as I get back up to speed. 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It would help if you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and/or parentheses.  It looks like you switched $(a-b)$ from numerator to denominator when you went from $(b-a)/(ab(a-b))$ to $(b-a)(a-b)/ab$, which is not generally correct; also $(a-b)(b-a)=ab-b^2-a^2\color{red}+ab$; also $(ab-b^2-a^2-ab)\color{red}-ab=-b^2-a^2-ab$, but that's not generally true for $(ab-b^2-a^2-ab)\color{red}/ab$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\dfrac1a-\dfrac1b}{a-b}= \dfrac{\dfrac{b-a}{ab}}{(a-b)}=\dfrac{b-a}{a-b}\dfrac1{ab}=\dfrac{-1}{ab}$$

Comment: with $a=x$ and $b=x+\Delta x$, this can be used to show $\dfrac d{dx}\dfrac1x=\dfrac{-1}{x^2}$

Comment: Many thanks J.W., Let me spend some time with this. I assumed ((b-a)/(ab)) / (a-b) would be simplified by flipping and multiplying (a-b)/1 (the denominator) and the numerator. The basic idea that you can factor out the numerator and multiply the entire remaining expression somehow missed me. Am I right here? That is: ((a/x)/y) = ((a/y)*(1/x)) I tried multiple examples and it seems to work. I just have forgotten basic algebra along the way here. Apologies.

Comment: Yes, $\dfrac {a/x}y=\dfrac a {xy}=\dfrac ay \dfrac 1x$